# std:thread on macOS: libc++abi.dylib: terminating

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos

While running the following very simple code

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void test() {cout << "hello" << endl;}

int main(){

    thread t(test);
    t.join();
}
```

And compiling with

> g++ -std=c++14 -pthread multi.cc

on macOS10.12.6 with clang 900.0.38, the program shows

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating Abort trap: 6

Does anyone know what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: osx 10.10.5, clang-700.1.81: no crash. what happens when you use `detach()` instead of join? (you should be getting minimal output, maybe `h` or `hel` and possibly no crash)

Comment: @kritzikratzi thanks for testing. The issue seems to have been fixed by rebooting twice(?). I guess it had something to do with macOS updates..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use `-pthread` option, as you are using `std::thread`

Compile with below command:

```
g++ -std=c++14 multi.cc -o multi
```